# Options for application communication between two android phones

Tags: android, connection

I need to establish communication between two android phones (same application, if it matters).

Is there any possibility for android applications to establish a data stream via bluetooth (so there is no need for internet connection)?

Or (UDP)TCP/IP over internet is currently best solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since Android 2.0 it should be possible to use the bluetooth API ([see here](http://developer.android.com/intl/fr/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html)).

Answer (score 0):

In android 1.5, i believe, there's no file transfer via bluetooth. In order to be version agnostic, [bump](http://bu.mp/) transfers all the data via their servers i believe.

Comment: I'm not talking about file transfer, but connecting applications on two android phones with each other (e.g. game multiplayer mode on two physically close phones, synchronization between same application on two phones...).